# What temperature does oxygen have to be at to bond with carbon monoxide?

Tags: gas-laws, temperature

I was wondering how I would go about calculating the required temperature of oxygen to bond one oxygen particle with carbon monoxide (CO). I know that it depends on some other factors such as air pressure, but that's the extent of my knowledge. I would be really grateful if someone could explain what environment I would need to combine the two.